# Get the value of the last parameter of urlreferrer which can be present twice (same key twice)

Tags: c#, url

I would like to get a specify parameter from my referrer url.
Till there no problems.

For the url :
http://mysite.fr?test=sfdfsdfsd&code=code1

To get the value of the code's parameter I use:

```
string code = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.UrlReferrer.Query)["code"];
```

But the point where I block is when the code parameter is present twice

For example, it possible that I get this specific url :
http://mysite.fr?test=sfdfsdfsd&code=code1&code=code2

In this case I have to get only the second code key (code2 value) but I don't find a simple method to get it.

If someone has an idea on that it will be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NameValueCollection.GetValues(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx) method. Is returns all values as a string array:

```
string url1 = "http://mysite.fr?test=sfdfsdfsd&code=code1";
string url2 = "http://mysite.fr?test=sfdfsdfsd&code=code1&code=code2";
string code1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url1).GetValues("code").LastOrDefault();
string code2 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url2).GetValues("code").LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this?

```
 var coll = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
 var values = coll.GetValues("code")[1];
```